# How to set `ignoreUnknownValues` option to `true` in BigQuery java client load job

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a java program that uses BigQuery Java client library to import JSON data from Google cloud storage into BigQuery. I am using `Table.load()` method to start the load job. How do I set the `ignoreUnknownValues` option to `true` for this load job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so here is how you do it.

```
val jobConf = LoadJobConfiguration
  .newBuilder(table.getTableId, path)
  .setIgnoreUnknownValues(true)
  .setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.json())
  .build()
val loadJob = bigQuery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(jobConf).build())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [docs](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.9.3/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/Table.html)

I think you cant use this flag with "load" because there are no flag "ignoreUnknownValues" into [BigQuery.JobOption](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.9.3/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQuery.JobOption.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

```
public Job load(FormatOptions format,
            String sourceUri,
            BigQuery.JobOption... options)
     throws BigQueryException
```

But you can try "insert" option instead "load":

```
public InsertAllResponse insert(Iterable<InsertAllRequest.RowToInsert> rows,
                            boolean skipInvalidRows,
                            boolean ignoreUnknownValues)
                     throws BigQueryException
```

so:

```
response = table.insert(rows, true, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `table.insert` won't work for me as I am importing data from a JSON file. I do not have the data loaded into memory.

Comment: In that case you can use [bq Command-Line Tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool)

Comment: But my question is about the java client library.